# How I am suppose to deal with indeterminations in a given relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose a relation $S = \{(x, y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}: x \text{ divides } y \}$

I'm curious about if $S$ is reflexive, symmetric, transitive, or antisymmetric.

The relation is not symmetric because considering $(\forall x\in \mathbb{Z})(\forall y\in \mathbb{Z})(xSy \to ySr)$ for $x=2$ and $y=4$, $\dfrac{1}{2}$ is not an integer.

The problem I see in the reflexive, transitive, and antisymmetric concerns the indetermination $\dfrac{0}{0}$. So the relation is not reflexive, symmetric, transitive, neither antisymmetric? If $(x, y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/\{0\}$ so the Relation S would be reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, x divides y if $\exists a\in\Bbb Z$ such that $y=ax$. Any integer $a$ satisfies $0=0a$, so $0$ divides $0$. So the relation is actually reflexive.

If $x\mid y,y\mid z$, write $y=ax,z=by$ whence $a,b\in \Bbb Z\implies z=b(ax)=(ba)x$, so z divides x, and thus $S$ is transitive in fact.

Comment: Thank you, It makes sense, So S is antisymmetric as well?

Comment: No, take -1 and 1